# Maven is over 100%! [downloading no-stop]

Tags: maven

I've imported a new project from our svn repo and maven started downloading all the dependencies.
And keep downloading...

What should I do? Kill it or just wait? Is this "normal"?

Note:
the problem is only with me, every other colleague had no problem. Is not a problem of lots of dependencies because in that case I guess it would just take time but not exceed the 100% ceiling.

[image]

Comment: [Pretty much](http://blog.sonatype.com/people/2011/04/how-not-to-download-the-internet/)

Comment: And how this could be related? And what's the downvote for? One thing is put lots of dependencies and have, obviously, a looooong download, another one is to have a problem with maven. Also because every colleague had no problem with this.

Comment: I can't answer your second question, because I didn't downvote you. And this is the kind of information you should be putting in your question :).

Comment: I guess the people should learn to comment before downvote (at least for not sure questions). Btw I was thinking it was obvious... anyway, also in case of lots of dependencies how can be a over-100% considered normal? :/

Comment: Well, it wasn't obvious to me, you might as well have been someone new to Maven (in which case it is completely valid to state that the build takes a long time). And, no, it isn't, it could be either an error in progress estimation or a bug somewhere else.

Comment: The over 100% thing I can't help you with.  But if you're taking a long time to download all the dependencies, you might talk to your fellow developers and see if you've got your global maven settings.xml right.  They may be pointing at a more local proxy repository that will deliver your artifacts faster than maven central can.

Comment: We already have all set up with our local repo. I've never had any problem with other projects. I'll update the question with these informations. Will be someone so kind to counter the downvote? I don't think this question deserves one.

Comment: Thanks, I've given up and canceled the progress. Everything seems fine (for now!). :p
Probably Eclipse messed up something, as always.